# Cannot make successful call using Jmeter to a rest service (Method: DELETE)

Tags: performance, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I have written a `REST` web-service. It accepts `RequestMethod.DELETE`, consumes  `"application/json"`. I have tested this in my local using `DHC` client of chrome. It was successful. But when I test it using Jmeter then the response is saying: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect". My point is then how it is working with dhc client & why not in Jmeter ?

[image]
[image]

**Java Portion:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/{apiVersion}/provision"}, 
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE, consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
EspCancelResponse cancel(@RequestBody EspCancelRequest cancelRequest) throws ProvisionException{
//do something
}
```

**[ESPCancelRequest:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOe9N.jpg)**

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"espCentralTransactionId"})
public class EspCancelRequest {

private String espCentralTransactionId;

public String getEspCentralTransactionId() {
    return espCentralTransactionId;
}

@JsonProperty("espCentralTransactionId")
public void setEspCentralTransactionId(String espCentralTransactionId) {
    this.espCentralTransactionId = espCentralTransactionId;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a bug in Jmeter. It is not able to send the body when the method is DELETE. I came to this understanding after seeing this post:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55255

:(. Thinking of using another tool or latest version.

Answer (score 0):

From your Java Portion:

> method = RequestMethod.DELETE, **consumes = "application/json")**

It might be due to your server treating your request body as a plain text.

Try adding [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) header with the value of [application/json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

The other reason could be your application server is [ignoring your message body](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3). Although DELETE methods are [allowed to have the body](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) it may be discarded by the server, your application lives on.

Comment: I have added a HTTP Header Manager already. Forgot to mention that

Comment: I have changed the queston a bit.. Using Jmeter I cant test it from my local also. The error is same. But using DHC client it is working fine.